# dynamodb ADD to null

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I need to do an Upadte-Expression on a number property called count, where I need to ADD numbers on each update. But the count property can be null initially or a number after incremented several times. DynamoDB does not allow to ADD on null values, so I need a kind of condition on my UpdateExression.

if count equals null: SET #count = :count

else: ADD #count :count

Is there a way to do this in one expression in DynamoDB ?

Comment: why don't you keep the count as zero initially rather than null?

Comment: No, currently we have to start with null as initial value

Comment: So you don't want the "count" attribute in the item in the first place. When you have the value for count, you would like to ADD or SET it? I don't think it can be achieved in one expression.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback